# Used matplotlib to subsection plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a ex.txt file as follows;

```
GA  1   90
GA  9   26  A
GA  30  42  B
GA  52  65  A
GA  77  84  C
BV  1   100
BV  14  18  A
BV  20  30  B
BV  60  80  C
```

And I want to plot it like this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPHAp.png). The same first columns is one group and first row is the total length. Subsequently, if the fourth column is "A" give a red rectangle. "B" give a blue rectangle...

I'm try this python code based on [matplotlib.pyplot](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html). But not working. Can help me to modify it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A='red'
B='blue'
C='purple'
gids = []
for cnt,line in enumerate(open("ex.txt")):
    ge = line.rstrip().split("\t")
    gid = ge[0]
    gids.append(gid)
    plt.plot([int(ge[1]),int(ge[2])],[cnt,cnt],linewidth=1,color='black')
    for start,stop in zip([int(s) for s in ge[1]],[int(s) for s in ge[2]]):
        if gid and next(ge[3]) == "A":
            plt.plot([start,stop],[cnt,cnt],linewidth=5,color=A)
        if gid and next(ge[3]) == "B":
            plt.plot([start,stop],[cnt,cnt],linewidth=5,color=B)
        if gid and next(ge[3]) == "C":
            plt.plot([start,stop],[cnt,cnt],linewidth=5,color=C)

plt.yticks(range(cnt+1),gids)
plt.ylim(-0.5,cnt+0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to separate code that parses the data from your plotting code. Below I hence have two functions, one that reads in the file and figures out the which line belongs to what box, etc (`parse()`), and then another function that actually plots one such set of boxes (`plot_box_string`). I use `Rectangle` patches instead of thick lines, as then you can specify your box heights in data coordinates as well.

Code is hopefully pretty self explanatory; if not, let me know in the comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def parse(file_path, letter_to_color):
    """
    Read in file and parse input.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    file_path -- str
        /path/to/file

    letter_to_color -- dict
        dictionary mapping last column to color

    Returns:
    --------
    box_strings -- dictionary of dictionaries
        box_string[key] (where key is specified by the first column of the input file)
        returns a dictionary with keys 'left', 'right', 'color', 'start', 'stop';

    """

    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # split lines, remove line breaks
    # lines = [line[:-1].split(' ') for line in lines]
    lines = [line.split(' ') for line in lines]
    lines = [[string.strip() for string in line] for line in lines]

    # remove extra white space
    lines = [[item for item in line if len(item)>0] for line in lines]

    box_strings = dict()
    for line in lines:
        try:
            key, left, right, letter = line
            box_strings[key]['left'].append(float(left))
            box_strings[key]['right'].append(float(right))
            box_strings[key]['color'].append(letter_to_color[letter])

        except ValueError: # start of a new box string
            key, start, stop = line
            box_strings[key] = dict()
            box_strings[key]['start'] = float(start)
            box_strings[key]['stop'] = float(stop)

            # initialise remaining atrributes
            box_strings[key]['left'] = []
            box_strings[key]['right'] = []
            box_strings[key]['color'] = []

    return box_strings

def plot_box_string(start, stop, left, right, color, bottom=0., height=1., ax=None):
    """
    Plots a bunch of boxes along a line.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    start  -- float
        start of line

    stop   -- float
        end of line

    left   -- iterable of floats
        x-coordinate specifying the left-hand side of the boxes

    right  -- iterable of floats
        x-coordinate specifying the right-hand side of the boxes

    color     -- list of valid color specifications
        rectangle colors

    bottom -- floats
        y-coordinate specifying the bottom of the boxes

    height    -- float
        y-offset from bottom specifying the top of the boxes

    ax        -- matplotlib axis instance

    Returns:
    --------
    None

    """

    if not ax:
        ax = plt.gca()

    ax.plot((start, stop), (bottom, bottom))

    for ii, (l,r,c) in enumerate(zip(left, right, color)):
        width = r-l
        patch = Rectangle((l, bottom), width, height, color=c)
        ax.add_artist(patch)

    return

# initialise figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# read in and parse text
letter_to_color = dict(
    A='red',
    B='blue',
    C='purple',
)
box_strings = parse("ex.txt", letter_to_color)

# plot string of boxes
for ii, (key, box_string) in enumerate(box_strings.iteritems()):
    ax.text(-10, ii, key)
    plot_box_string(box_string['start'],
                    box_string['stop'],
                    box_string['left'],
                    box_string['right'],
                    box_string['color'],
                    bottom=ii,
                    height=0.6,
                    ax=ax
    )

# set xlim, ylim;
# need to do this manually, as patches are not registered by matplotlib automagically
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 3.1)
ax.set_xlim(-20, 110)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I get a different [figure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4N58_pNXx8heVNKNUVSdEduM1U/view?usp=sharing) when try this code in my computer.

Comment: Strange, it gets the first box string right and then fails on the second. Can you add `print box_strings['BV']` and post the output?

Comment: Also, check that your ex.txt is not corrupted. The way that you read in files is dangerous. It might also be that your ex.txt has extraneous white space characters (maybe a tab space somewhere?) that didn't get transfered when you posted the text.

Comment: I reproduce the exact error when I substitute the last line in ex.txt `BV  60  80  C` with `BV  60  80`. Check that line in the document you are loading. Something is off with it.

Comment: I used python2.7 and matplotlib-1.4.3.

Comment: `str.split(',')` splits a string after a comma. Given the example data you provided (where entries are probably delimited by a tab), that makes no sense at all.

Comment: I want to exclude the problem, so replace it with a clearer comma delimiter.

Comment: And {'color': [], 'start': 60.0, 'right': [], 'stop': 80.0, 'left': []} is the output when print box_strings['BV'] . Strange, when I copy all the data twice in [ex2.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kJVjIIErMfjjKiLRhdX9ZL40pqjHUqOmrK4eBB1-hvg) file, I get this [figure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4N58_pNXx8helhfMzNxZERGWEk).

Comment: I think what is happening, is that it is reading in the file apart from the very last character. Hence when the program parses the last line, it doesn't see a color specification, so it initialises a new box_string dictionary that overrides the current one. To confirm this, can you add `print lines` before `# split lines, remove line breaks` and post the output?

Comment: ``['GA 1 90\n', 'GA 9 26 A\n', 'GA 30 42 B\n', 'GA 52 65 A\n', 'GA 77 84 C\n', 'BV 1 100\n', 'BV 14 18 A\n', 'BV 20 30 B\n', 'BV 60 80 C']``

Comment: Ah, there is no line break at the end of the very last line.... That is easily fixed. Give me a minute.

Comment: Yes, The figure same with you post when I add the line break in last character.

Comment: More prefect if it can automatically estimate the ``xlim`` in ``ax.set_xlim(0.5, 110)`` .

Comment: Ok, I changed the code so it will still work even if the the last line break is missing. If this works for you now, please accept the answer.

Comment: To set the xlimits automatically, just find out the minimum and maximum of in your second and third column, respectively. I am sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Good idea. I'm understand.